# Bug 3DTouch Keyboard Text Selection [_NSActivityAssertion setCursorPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, 3dtouch

I'm using Hakawai framework (a mention framework in a UITextView) but when use iOS Keyboard with a device with `3D Touch` and select text with `3DTouch` option in keyboard, the application crashes :

> [_NSActivityAssertion setCursorPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance occurs to
>
> [NSString setCursorPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was when the textView runs `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` to change Spell Checking while Keyboard 3D Touch Selector is working, then the selector try to call the next focused object (while is in `becomeFirstResponder`)